# All values Typescript Array is last value

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, typescript

I call static function `wrap` with list which contains different parameters. But function return array with the same values (last value)

```js
export class BindablePrimitive<T> {

    constructor(val?: T) {
        if (val != undefined) this.value = val;
    }

    value: T;

    static wrap<T>(list: Array<T>): Array<BindablePrimitive<T>> {
        let result = new Array<BindablePrimitive<T>>();
        if (list) {
            for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                let item = list[i];
                result.push(new BindablePrimitive<T>(item));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
 }

 /*Expected result: 
 BindablePrimitive[0]: 'text1'
 BindablePrimitive[1]: 'text2'
 BindablePrimitive[2]: 'text3'

 Actual result:
 BindablePrimitive[0]: 'text3'
 BindablePrimitive[1]: 'text3'
 BindablePrimitive[2]: 'text3' */
```

Can Webpack affect on it? Or typescript version?

Comment: works for me...

Comment: Its working as expected. Verified on TS playground as well. http://codepen.io/jsreekanth/pen/bBrGZE?editors=1111

Comment: @Sreekanth maybe it's webpack affect?

Comment: @Zverit, Can you put your test code that was invoking the `wrap` function in your question?